# WPF: Create a dialog / prompt

Tags: wpf, xaml, dialog, prompt

I need to create a Dialog / Prompt including TextBox for user input. My problem is, how to get the text after having confirmed the dialog? Usually I would make a class for this which would save the text in a property. However I want do design the Dialog using XAML. So I would somehow have to extent the XAML Code to save the content of the TextBox in a property - but I guess that's not possible with pure XAML. What would be the best way to realize what I'd like to do? How to build a dialog which can be defined from XAML but can still somehow return the input? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The "responsible" answer would be for me to suggest building a ViewModel for the dialog and use two-way databinding on the TextBox so that the ViewModel had some "ResponseText" property or what not. This is easy enough to do but probably overkill.

The pragmatic answer would be to just give your text box an x:Name so that it becomes a member and expose the text as a property in your code behind class like so:

```
<!-- Incredibly simplified XAML -->
<Window x:Class="MyDialog">
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="Enter some text" />
       <TextBox x:Name="ResponseTextBox" />
       <Button Content="OK" Click="OKButton_Click" />
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Then in your code behind...

```
partial class MyDialog : Window {

    public MyDialog() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ResponseText {
        get { return ResponseTextBox.Text; }
        set { ResponseTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

Then to use it...

```
var dialog = new MyDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
    MessageBox.Show("You said: " + dialog.ResponseText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Josh and sorry for my late reply! I initially was focused too much on loading XAML from a file instead of just creating a class like shown by you.

Comment: You need to handle the OK button click event and set this.DialogResult = true; to close the dialog and have dialog.ShowDialog() == true.

Comment: I found a nice simple prompt dialog ready to use [link](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/creating-a-custom-input-dialog/)

Comment: Just one problem I can see here, that this dialog has also maximaze button and minimaze button.... Is it possible to disable this buttons?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko since this is a normal Windows, you can use the properties [`ResizeMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstyle) and [`WindowStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstyle) to hide title bar and/or the minimize/maximize buttons. I don't know if you can just disable them, though.

Answer (score 46):

Edit: Can be installed with nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/PromptDialog/

I just add a static method to call it like a MessageBox:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    x:Class="utils.PromptDialog"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    MinWidth="300"
    MinHeight="100"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<StackPanel Margin="5">
    <TextBlock Name="txtQuestion" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtResponse" Margin="5"/>
    <PasswordBox Name="txtPasswordResponse" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="_Ok" IsDefault="True" Margin="5" Name="btnOk" Click="btnOk_Click" />
        <Button Content="_Cancel" IsCancel="True" Margin="5" Name="btnCancel" Click="btnCancel_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class PromptDialog : Window
{
    public enum InputType
    {
        Text,
        Password
    }

    private InputType _inputType = InputType.Text;

    public PromptDialog(string question, string title, string defaultValue = "", InputType inputType = InputType.Text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(PromptDialog_Loaded);
        txtQuestion.Text = question;
        Title = title;
        txtResponse.Text = defaultValue;
        _inputType = inputType;
        if (_inputType == InputType.Password)
            txtResponse.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            txtPasswordResponse.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    void PromptDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inputType == InputType.Password)
            txtPasswordResponse.Focus();
        else
            txtResponse.Focus();
    }

    public static string Prompt(string question, string title, string defaultValue = "", InputType inputType = InputType.Text)
    {
        PromptDialog inst = new PromptDialog(question, title, defaultValue, inputType);
        inst.ShowDialog();
        if (inst.DialogResult == true)
            return inst.ResponseText;
        return null;
    }

    public string ResponseText
    {
        get
        {
            if (_inputType == InputType.Password)
                return txtPasswordResponse.Password;
            else
                return txtResponse.Text;
        }
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
        Close();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

So you can call it like:

```
string repeatPassword = PromptDialog.Prompt("Repeat password", "Password confirm", inputType: PromptDialog.InputType.Password);
```

Comment: +1 For implementing a `MessageBox`-style static method. Concise, reusable code!

Comment: As soon as I saw the word "static" I ignored the other answers. Thank you! :)

Comment: I make a nuget package to include on your projects: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PromptDialog/

Answer (score 17):

Great answer of Josh, all credit to him, I slightly modified it to this however:

MyDialog Xaml

```
    <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <TextBlock Name="TitleTextBox" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
        <TextBox Name="InputTextBox" Padding="3,3,3,3" />
        <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Name="BtnOk" Content="OK" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" Padding="8" Click="BtnOk_Click" />
            <Button Name="BtnCancel" Content="Cancel" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="8" Click="BtnCancel_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

MyDialog Code Behind

```
    public MyDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyDialog(string title,string input)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TitleText = title;
        InputText = input;
    }

    public string TitleText
    {
        get { return TitleTextBox.Text; }
        set { TitleTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public string InputText
    {
        get { return InputTextBox.Text; }
        set { InputTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public bool Canceled { get; set; }

    private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canceled = true;
        Close();
    }

    private void BtnOk_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canceled = false;
        Close();
    }
```

And call it somewhere else

```
var dialog = new MyDialog("test", "hello");
dialog.Show();
dialog.Closing += (sender,e) =>
{
    var d = sender as MyDialog;
    if(!d.Canceled)
        MessageBox.Show(d.InputText);
}
```

Comment: You should replace (in your grid definition xaml) 50* and 50* with * and * because there is no need for 50.

Comment: Tip: setting `WindowStyle="ToolWindow"` on the Window makes it look even nicer. Also `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` and `dialog.Owner = this;` positions it in the center of the parent window

Answer (score 6):

You don't need **ANY** of these other fancy answers.  Below is a simplistic example that doesn't have all the `Margin`, `Height`, `Width` properties set in the XAML, but should be enough to show how to get this done at a basic level.

**XAML**
Build a `Window` page like you would normally and add your fields to it, say a `Label` and `TextBox` control inside a `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Name="lblUser" Content="User Name:" />
    <TextBox Name="txtUser" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then create a standard `Button` for Submission ("OK" or "Submit") and a "Cancel" button if you like:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Name="btnSubmit" Click="btnSubmit_Click" Content="Submit" />
    <Button Name="btnCancel" Click="btnCancel_Click" Content="Cancel" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Code-Behind**
You'll add the `Click` event handler functions in the code-behind, but when you go there, first, declare a public variable where you will store your textbox value:

```
public static string strUserName = String.Empty;
```

Then, for the event handler functions (right-click the `Click` function on the button XAML, select "Go To Definition", it will create it for you), you need a check to see if your box is empty. You store it in your variable if it is not, and close your window:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
    {
        strUserName = txtUser.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Must provide a user name in the textbox.");
}
```

**Calling It From Another Page**
You're thinking, if I close my window with that `this.Close()` up there, my value is gone, right?  **NO!!** I found this out from another site:  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/359208-wpf-how-to-make-simple-popup-window-for-input/

They had a similar example to this (I cleaned it up a bit) of how to open your `Window` from another and retrieve the values:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpenPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopupWindow popup = new MyPopupWindow();  // this is the class of your other page

        //ShowDialog means you can't focus the parent window, only the popup
        popup.ShowDialog(); //execution will block here in this method until the popup closes

        string result = popup.strUserName;
        UserNameTextBlock.Text = result;  // should show what was input on the other page
    }
}
```

**Cancel Button**
You're thinking, well what about that Cancel button, though?  So we just add another public variable back in our pop-up window code-behind:

```
public static bool cancelled = false;
```

And let's include our `btnCancel_Click` event handler, and make one change to `btnSubmit_Click`:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    cancelled = true;
    strUserName = String.Empty;
    this.Close();
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
    {
        strUserName = txtUser.Text;
        cancelled = false;  // <-- I add this in here, just in case
        this.Close();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Must provide a user name in the textbox.");
}
```

And then we just read that variable in our `MainWindow` `btnOpenPopup_Click` event:

```
private void btnOpenPopup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPopupWindow popup = new MyPopupWindow();  // this is the class of your other page
    //ShowDialog means you can't focus the parent window, only the popup
    popup.ShowDialog(); //execution will block here in this method until the popup closes

    // **Here we find out if we cancelled or not**
    if (popup.cancelled == true)
        return;
    else
    {
        string result = popup.strUserName;
        UserNameTextBlock.Text = result;  // should show what was input on the other page
    }
}
```

Long response, but I wanted to show how easy this is using `public static` variables.  No `DialogResult`, no returning values, nothing.  Just open the window, store your values with the button events in the pop-up window, then retrieve them afterwards in the main window function.

Comment: There a lot of way to improve the provided code: 1) don't use static for storing data, otherwise you'll occasionally run into problems with several dialogs; 2) there is DialogResult to "pass" 'true' via ShowDialog(); 3) IsCancel attribute for a button makes it a true Cancel button without any extra code...

Comment: @AntonK 1) Using static objects is how you can call variables in other classes without having to instantiate them all the time.  To me, static variables cut out all that and are far preferable. Never had a problem with them, because they will get reset anytime the object (Window, Page) that has them is opened.  If you want several dialogs, create a dialog for each one - don't use the same one over and over or yes, that is problematic - but also bad coding, because why would you want the same dialog 50 times?

Comment: @AntonK 2) You can't pass back `DialogResult` in WPF, it's `MessageBoxResult`, which I found only works from standard buttons on a `MessageBox.Show()` dialog - not one from a custom dialog shown through `.ShowDialog()` - and can only query for the standard operators, `MessageBoxResult.OK`, `MessageBoxResult.Cancel`, "Yes", "No", etc. - not Booleans or custom values.  3) `IsCancel` would require storing it in a Boolean and sending that back, anyway, so this was a one-size-fits-all solution.